# Eclipse Subversive - svn checkout gives error.

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive, svnkit

When i try to checkout my project from svn server it gives me `svn: E200030: Invalid expression` error. My eclipse is `Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600` and it has the futures like in the image. [image: installed futures] . I use Subversive and SvnKit. I am connected svn server but When i try to checkout a project the error appears like [image: this]. Any small clue or help will be appreciated. Regards.

Comment: It looks like an issue of SvnKit ([see `E200030` bug reports](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?list_id=17045822&longdesc=E200030&longdesc_type=allwordssubstr&query_format=advanced)). Does updating or switching the connector fix your problem (_Window > Preferences: Team > SVN_, tab _SVN Connector_)?

Comment: I have 2 SVNKit, one is SVNKit 1.7.14 and other is SVNKit 1.8.12. Switch not changing error.

Comment: Here you find the latest connectors: `http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/eclipse/6.0/update-site/` Consider also update Subversive: `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/4.0/update-site/`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked now.